# Shiny- Date and Time displays "T" and "Z"?

Tags: r, date, time, shiny

I query date and time date via SQL in Shiny. R displays them in the following way: "**2017-05-03 21:56:14 BST**" and the data type is:"POSIXct" "POSIXt".

However when I output this date in Shiny my browser displays: 
2017-05-05T21:56:14Z.

Is there any way to remove "T" and "Z" separators but still keep the date data types due to ordering reasons by this Date and Time column?

P.s. I tried to change this over to character type, but then I lost the ability to order properly DESC/ASC...

Thanks

Comment: Convert it to character `as.character(Time)`

Comment: Thanks- I have done it then I lost the ability to order by this column. E.g. my date/time ranges from 27 April to 5 May. It ordered in the following way for DESC: 1 May, 2 May, 3 May, 4 May, 5 May, then 30 April, 29 April etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `strftime` to format dates.

> strftime(Sys.time(), format = '%Y-%m-%d %R')

Depending on how your code is written, it might be better to only use `strftime` inside the `renderDataTable` instead of formatting the original dataset (to maintain other properties.

Comment: In my opinion this is not a valid solution since strftime converts a date column to a string column that cannot be properly be ordered anymore.